# How to make my app run only on iPads with retina display?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina-display

I have an app that creates graphics and I've only tested it on an iPad with retina display (screen scale of 2). Because the app heavily depends on this screen density, I'm looking for a way to exclude earlier versions of iPad, as well as iPad mini from being able to download my app from the app store.

**Is there some xCode project flag or some device feature that I can use to make sure that my iOS 6.0 app would not be sold to devices which do not have retina displays?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that any attempt to do that would get dinged by the App Store guardians. You can exclude the iPad 1 by requiring iOS 6 but that's as far as you can go.